# How to resolve an error like "Assembly "AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.605" on execution of JMeter Script?

Tags: jmeter, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a JMeter load test script for .Net Version 4.8 framework. It's successfully passed but on re-execution or on increasing thread group count it throws an error like "Assembly "AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" does not contain a script with hash code "de1feab2"." in View result Tree in JMeter. Also attached Screenshot for your reference.

I have already handled ViewState and EventValidation. Also the created test script is working fine for thread group count 1. Can you please help me with steps to maintain the ScriptManager's hidden value as it's value is static in all the created steps in a script. Please reply asap.Actually, I need an immediate solution to the mentioned problem statement. [Screenshot of Error throwing in JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZDui.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), for example you're sending a hard-coded (recorded?) parameter `de1feab2` and its value is supposed to be dynamic.

You can record your scenario one more time and compare JMeter test plans - all the values which differ are a subject to correlation.

Another option is considering an alternative recording solution like [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80), it's capable of exporting recorded network traffic in "[SmartJMX](https://riptutorial.com/jmeter/example/27934/automated-correlation-by-using-blazemeter-s--smartjmx-)" form with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters